# Different translations per environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I'd like certain translations to have different values depending on the environment.

```
Rails.env.test? && I18n.t('foo') # => 'A value'
Rails.env.development? && I18n.t('foo') # => 'A different value'
```

For accomplishing this I can imagine a few approaches:

- Ability to embed ERB in en.yml
- Ability to create per-environment locale files, e.g. en.test.yml
- Ability to directly set an entry: `I18n.set('foo', 'bar') if Rails.env.test?`

However I couldn't find any of these solutions ready to use.

Is there one?

Answer (score 2):

I think that You need something like this:

`en.production.yml`:

```
en:
  production:
    foo: "Foo"
    bar: "Bar"
```

`en.development.yml`:

```
en:
  development:
    foo: "foo"
    bar: "bar"
```

`en.test.yml`:

```
en:
  test:
    foo: "-foo-"
    bar: "-bar-"
```

and using is views and controllers:

```
I18n.t("#{Rails.env}.foo")
I18n.t("#{Rails.env}.bar")
```

---

Update:

If You just need to substitute variables to translation, use interpolation:

`en.yml`:

```
en:
  foo: "Foo %{variable}"
  bar: "%{var} Bar"
```

and using:

```
I18n.t('foo', :variable => 'Bar')
I18n.t('bar', :var => 'Foo')
```

Comment: That's not a generally good solution - it doesn't allow one to override arbitrary keys with per-env values.

Comment: Then look [pluralization rules](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#pluralization) - may be Ruby on Rails allows another translation rules, not only for plurals?

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the right direction. `I18n.backend.store_translations` allows to override entries, in an env-dependent way if one wants to. Add that to your answer and I'll accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party. I've created a gem that does that by using environment variables. [i18n-env-var-lookup](https://github.com/StaymanHou/i18n-env-var-lookup) . You can use it in combination with an environment variable loader such as [dotenv-rails](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)

My specific use case is a bit unique though. In our org, we have an existing rails app that we wanted to "white-label" for another project by another team in the org. We wanted to share the same source code repo for both projects while only change the site name. Given that there are already a few thousands entries in the locale files and close to a hundred of them contain the site name, it would be a bad practice to update all the templates to pass the site name as a variable. Other suggestions that we found in related questions are also no good in our case. We want to keep the locale files exactly the same for both project so that we can avoid messing with the source code and manage the locale files easily with 3rd-party localization service.

Therefore we turned to implementing the gem, and it solves our exact problem.